# pyspark combined standard deviation?

Tags: python, statistics, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data frame which consists of multiple standard deviations with mean and count of each. my df is as follows

```
| N| Mean | Std |
| -| ---- | --- |
| 1|     3|    2|
| 2|     4|    3|
```

I want to calculate combined standard deviation and mean from these.
(Since calculating mean and standard deviation for whole set where i need, i woud like to narrow down that operation like this)
I am trying to iterate dataframe row by row and do following operation

```
  std = sqrt(((n1-1) * pow(s1,2) + (n2-1) * pow(s2,2)) / (n1 + n2 + 1) + (n1 * n2 * pow(m1 - m2, 2))/((n1 + n2) * (n1 + n2 - 1)))
```

note that one of the S1,S2 here is combine std upto that row.

Can some one help me to do this?